# Vue JS Keyframes with js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, rotation

I'm trying to set the value of a `@keyframe` transform pro grammatically.

```
.spin {
    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(1665deg);
    }
```

I need to alter the 100% value to one I generate with JavaScript

```
spinWheel() {
    let segments = [], segmentSize, winningSegment, app = this;

    app.spin = 'spin';
    //each segment
    segmentSize = 360 / 6;
    for(let i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        segments[i] = i*segmentSize;
    }
    winningSegment = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    let start = winningSegment === 0 ? 0 : segments[winningSegment];
    let end   = winningSegment === 5 ? 360 : segments[winningSegment+1];
    let winningArea = {start: start  , end: end };

    app.start = 0;
    app.end = (360 * Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 15 + 1) + 15)) + Math.floor(Math.random() * (winningArea.end - winningArea.start + 1) + winningArea.start);

}
```

So when the method `spinWheel()` is run

```
100% {
    transform: rotate(end);
}
```

Would change to the app.end value.

I just can't seem to figure out how to do this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Creating or modifying keyframes in JavaScript is problematic. Would you be open to using Web Animations API? You'd need to polyfill it for any non-Chrome browsers, but there is a good Polyfill available.

Comment: open to anything that leads to a solution, I'm using VueJs (because I am using a laravel backend and vue came with it) if there is anything available for that.

Wouldn't mind something that fires events when the transition has finished too as I will need that soon.

Comment: Definitely have a look at Web Animations API then. It allows keyframe-based animations using `element.animate(keyframes, options)`, which returns an `Animation` instance that emits a `finish` event. Sounds like a perfect fit.